# Private contexts and their parents in CoreData

Tags: swift, ios, core-data

I find myself following this pattern a lot in my core data code, which works, but I'm wondering if it is needed...

```
let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
privateContext.parent = mainThreadContext

/// Do some stuff on the private context

privateContext.save()
/// Save parent on parent's queue
if let parent = privateContext.parent {
 parent.performAndWait{
  do {
   try parent.save()
  } catch {}
 }
}
```

I know that saving the private context after I make changes to it is needed, but I'm wondering if I have to explicitly save the parent context back on it's own queue.

I've been profiling my app and I was spending a lot of extra time doing uneeded saves other places, so I'm trying to trim the coredata code as much as possible.

Comment: Not really pseudo code, just didn't have all of the non-relevant implementation. Updated to be correct swift syntax.

Comment: ok, great, now let see what swift experts think of it ;-)